# How to set up a cookie to store the state of the page after .animate()

Tags: jquery, cookies

I have a page consisting of two panels: a fixed sidebar to the left and the fluid content to its right.

I also have a button that triggers an animate effect, partially hiding the sidebar.

My question is: how can I keep the left panel hidden after page refresh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set cookie, and check it value, to determinate how to show your side bar. to manipulate cookie, there is nice [plugin](http://javascriptmvc.com/docs.html#!jQuery.cookie)